# Deleting computer objects from AD in Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016

There is a big list of Computer objects in the AD of which most of them are not being used or they are de-active. So, I wanted to remove those which are not required. But before that, I wanted to know what happens when we delete a computer object from the active directory ? Will the object's data will be removed completely removed ?

Comment: The objects data? Do you mean files on the actual computer? If so, then no, no data will be removed from the actual computer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it's not about the user data. Will there be no data associated with the computer object in the Active Directory ? What happens if we remove or delete a computer object from the AD ? Will it be completely removed or any of its data will still be present on the AD ?

Comment: You may need to delete the DNS A record for the computer. There should be no other data in AD for the computer.

Comment: Use the PS command `Get-ADComputer SomeComputerName -Properties *`.  That is the data that is stored.

Answer (score 2):

Active Directory, depending on your version - supports a recycle bin - you might be able to enable it.

Besides that, best practice is to deactivate them - see what happens - wait a few weeks, then delete. Worst case, you need to re-join them to the domain.

Having said all of this - you should have a proper asset management system that allows you to track this information and even automatically compare so you know what should be there and what not and what the status of the asset is.

Deploy and Retire checklists should also cover those points - if possible with automated powershell scripts...

As for the data - if you delete it from AD the information from the object will be removed. Using the recycle bin function in AD allows you to quick recover it. Otherwise, it becomes a bigger challenge depending on your backup procedures..

Comment: can you please tell me, what will be the data associated with a computer object when it is created or removed from the AD ? Because, in case of removing local User account, all the system data associated with the user account will not be removed right ? In the same way, what happens if we remove a computer object from the AD ?

Comment: What data is stored in the computer object depends all on your Active Directory schema - this data will be removed. This will not have any impact on DNS nor the data that is stored on the hard drive of the real computer - it will only remove the object from Active Directory.